# How to publish project with non-public dependencies?

Tags: java, oracle, maven, ojdbc

I have Oracle JDBC driver at my project (ojdbc8.jar)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

It's installed at my local maven repository:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Oracle\Client\jdbc\lib\ojdbc8.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc8 -Dversion=12.2.0.1 -Dpackaging=jar
```

But now I want to distribute my project, for example at GitHub

If someone will download my project he won't have a ojdbc8.jar

So question is - how to publish project with some local or additional dependencies, which aren't at maven public repo?

Comment: Add a section to your `README.md`  that tells where and how to get this 3rd party libs. In your POM set them in scope `provided`.

Comment: Why `provided`? `optional` seems to be more appropriate...

Comment: @JFMeier IMHO `optional` means: the projects compiles without but the result misses some freature, whereas `provided` means: you have to get it anyhow to make the project compile.

Comment: @JFMeier from maven website: *"Optional dependencies are used when it's not really possible (for whatever reason) to split a project up into sub-modules. The idea is that some of the dependencies are only used for certain features in the project, and will not be needed if that feature isn't used."*

Comment: Ok, this is probably neither `provided` (the container provides it for you) nor `optional` (which, as you said, is also not the right thing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this problem when working with jars from companies, usually Microsoft and Apple, that would prefer that folks use their language stack instead of Java.  I'm not a lawyer, but you probably want to instruct folks who want to compile your code to start with the publicly downloadable jar, instead of pointing them to a maven artifact that you've built.

If there's no public repository then you should describe how to build the dependency in the user's local/corporate repository.  Give the URL needed to download the jar and describe the manual steps (the ones you used to build your copy) so that interested parties can follow along. As you've mentioned, maven makes it simple to deploy jars into a repository.

Comment: Thanks, it's really looks like the most "right" way

Answer (score 1):

If there is a publicly available repository that contains the ojdbc8.jar, you can define that repository in your pom.

If not, you need to find out whether you are allowed to publish that jar in your github repository or if you can find a download link.

Comment: oracle has an repository but you have to register and login to access it: http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/application/maven/index.html